# when installed chaincode I get the error could not connect to ordering service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I have a multihost network running on three separate hosts (with docker swarm).

In testing these hosts were all on the same subnet and everything worked fine.
Now I have migrated a host on another external network connected via vpn, I can create the containers, the channel and join all the peers to the channel, but when I install the chaincode it blocks when it has to install it on the peer located in the host external to the network.

The error that is returned to me is the following:

"Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer.xxx.xxx:7050': failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded channel = mychannel"

The orderer is located on a separate host and the IP address of the orderer has been added in / etc / hosts.

Would anyone know how to help me?

update:
I suspect it is a timeout problem.
In practice, the host leader sends the request to all peers who install the chaincode, but when this request arrives at the external host, it cannot receive a response before the waiting time expires.
But I don't know how to change this parameter.

I post the contents of the docker logs:

1. Host leader
   [image]
2. External host

[image]